# $S\neq \emptyset \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed and bounded,and $I = [$ Inf $S$, Sup $S ]$, prove that $I-S$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Let $S$ be a non-empty, closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $I = [$ Inf $S$, Sup $S ]$, prove that $I-S$ is an open set.

**My attempt**: Since $S$ is a bounded set, S must have a supremum and infimum by Completeness property of $\mathbb{R}$. $S$ is also closed, so it must contain all of its limit points, Hence Inf $S$, Sup $S$ $\in S$.

I am not able to further progress in this proof. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Take a point $x$ in I-S. Since S is closed, $x$ is not a limit point of S. What can we say about neighborhoods of $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $S$ is non-empty, closed and bounded we have $\{\inf S,\sup S\}\subseteq S$ (as you stated yourself).

Consequently $I-S=J-S=J\cap S^{\complement}$ where $J$ is the set $(\inf S,\sup S)$.

The sets $J$ and $S^{\complement}$ are both open, so also their intersection is open.